# Update users field on account using workflow or process builder

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder

I have one field on user (Employee Number).
Whenever the status of the account (Status__c) change to 'permanant'.
I need to capture the employee Number in one of the account field ,who will chnage the status.

Is this possible using workflow/process builder and if any solution .please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sam yes you can do it with help of woerkflow rule- create a workflow rule on Account, in the criteria set the criteria. Then in field update Select the field and set the value as something like this -"LastModifiedBy.Employee_Number__c". hope this helps

Comment: @sam please mark it as best answer!!